# How to unit test a class returning all subordinate roles for a given role?

Tags: apex, unit-test, role-hierarchy

I have an apex class which returns all subordinate roles for a given Role (all roles are non-portal). The class is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861275/get-all-roles-under-current-users-role/10863247#10863247) one and returns a set of IDs for all roles below the given role.

For the unit test class however, I have the below challenges:

1. I cannot assert the number of subordinate roles for a given role as in different environments, I have slightly different role hierarchy
2. Besides asserting perhaps the number of SOQL queries used for each call to this method, what can I assert?

Note: I'm not sure if this question is too subjective to be here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to insert test "UserRole" records in your test class as below :

```
@testsetup
static void createUserRole() {
    UserRole ur = new UserRole(Name = 'CEO');
    insert ur;
}
```

If there is a hierarchy of roles you want to test, create one userrole record for parent and use "parentroleId" on the next record to reference parentrole.

Comment: I setup a small tree of roles and asserted different scenarios. Cheers!